# android listfragment + swiping through items

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, swipe

I'm developing an app, which consist of:
 1. main activity, which has action bar, list fragment and some buttons at bottom
 2. when you click on some item, another activity is launched - some buttons at top and webview under it.

I have everything working, but now I have to implement swiping between items from list, and I cant figure out how to swipe between activities. I though of changing items into fragments but then I have no idea, how layout should be worked out. I've read blog about viewpager, but as I understood, you can swipe only between 5 tabs with it, and I have 20+ items in listfragment. any ideas? thanks

Comment: You want a scroll view which stops on each page that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one Activity with ViewPager as it's main control. change items into fragments and add them to the ViewPager via FragmentAdapter

Comment: so u are saying that I should create only one activity and put there listfragment which will change into fragment which will show item. and how to take care of other interface? like those buttons?

Comment: no no, one Activity which will show ListFragment, and another with ViewPager

Comment: ahh I get it now. wow nice idea. and can you please tell me how to use viewpager for many items? because in example was just one swich which shown one of 5 tabs.. is there some method like "onLeftSwipe" or something?

Comment: you need an adapter for your viewPager, there you can specify how many items you want.

viewpager has onSelected() method which tells you what item is currently selected

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and user viewpager. there is no arbitrary limit to the number of pages.

It would be the quickest solution for you and seems to cover what you are doing.

Comment: i dont understand what you just said